# Independent iPhone Developer Network

Tags: iphone, macos

Hi I'm currently doing some independent development on the iPhone and Mac. Loving the freedom but the single biggest thing I miss about working with a team of developers is the opportunity to talk through design choices and issues with other developers.

I'm not talking about general "humm ..." questions (there is stackoverflow for that ;)) I'm talking about things that are not for public consumption or are very specific to your application. I'm thinking about something that is a little more interactive (for example screen sharing and chatting).

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Cocoaheads groups in various cities, that usually have monthly meetings... also there are NSCoder groups, that have a bunch of people working together for a day or so once a week.

Answer (score 0):

IRC sounds like a good place for such discussions. Some iPhone development related channels you may be interested in:

- [I don't know any, community wiki'ing this so others can add them]